# how to get documents attached to a list item via graph api or sdk method?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

Need to fetch this csv file from the list item via api/sdk method. Tried this api:
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/siteId/lists/listId/items/itemId , got the list item but not the attachments in it.

Answer (score 0):

CRUD operations for list item's attachment are not supported by Graph API.

According [this](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-graph/missing-api-to-work-with-spo-list-item-attachments/m-p/2225728) list item's attachment feature is in backlog.

Alternative is to use SharePoint API.

Answer (score 0):

Its right as user2250152 mentioned,list items attachment is not supported by graph but you can raise a feature request here: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

My work-around was to not use attachments, but to add a column of type image instead. This column can get fetched with the `/items/itemId` endpoint. It returns a string that can be JSON-deserialized, and contains the URL of the image - which is quite a WTF, but does the trick for me.
Of course, this doesn't save your *** if you have a non-image attachment...